# Mark a position between 2 characters

Tags: ide, monaco-editor

I often use markers to underline a part of code (e.g., to invite users to hover on it and see hints). Most of time, we want to underline at least one characters. But sometimes, we may want to underline the position between two characters. For instance, given a formula `fg(23,)`, I want to underline the position between `,` and `)`, then hovering on it shows `a non-empty argument is expected here`.

It seems that the following code in the [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) can achieve this more or less.

```
var ed = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "fg(23,)",
    language: "javascript"
});

monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(ed.getModel(), 'test', [{
    startLineNumber: 1,
    startColumn: 7,
    endLineNumber: 1,
    endColumn: 7,
    message: "a non-empty argument is expected here",
    severity: 8
}])
```

However, setting `startColumn` same as `endColumn` does not always do the trick. For instance, I cannot underline the position between `(` and `2`; setting `startColumn: 4, endColumn: 4` does not work.

So does anyone know how to mark a position between 2 characters? We are not limited to underlining, other ways like highlighting are welcomed as well.

(* Link on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3039 *)

Comment: I would always include the character following the error position, because this is where the error actually occurs. This way you always have something that shows with an error marker.

Answer (score 0):

To your question: following [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/44) post, it seems that a solution may look something like this (please use the [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) to test)

HTML

```
<div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>
```

CSS

```
.formulaHighlight {  /* this class name can be whatever you want */
    color: #3456ff !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: oblique;
}
```

JS

```
const ed = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "fg(23,)",
    language: "javascript"
});

monaco.editor.setModelMarkers(ed.getModel(), 'test', [{
    startLineNumber: 1,
    startColumn: 7,
    endLineNumber: 1,
    endColumn: 7,
    message: "a non-empty argument is expected here",
    severity: 8
}])

const decorations = ed.deltaDecorations(
    [],
    [
        {
            range: new monaco.Range(1, 4, 1, 6),
            options: { inlineClassName: 'formulaHighlight' }
        }
    ]
);
```

The `delta decoration` method allow to customize styles in specific locations. The `monaco.Range` method uses the following parameters:

- `startLineColumn` - from which line to start the highlight
- `startColumn` - the numeric value of the first highlight character
- `endLineNumber` - which line stops the highlight
- `endColumn` - the numeric value of last highlighted character

In your case it seems that `startLineColumn` and `endLineNumber` will be the same line number. Also,`startColumn` and `endColumn` will represent the actual highlight range (within the same line)

Comment: Hello, did you answer to my question? My question is about how to mark a position between 2 characters (e.g., between `(` and `2`)) rather than decorating `23`.

Comment: hmm.. can you please add a screenshot or an illustration that demonstrate your intention?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626893/shift-the-underline-to-the-right) is a solution using decoration and css. With regards to this question, we are not necessarily limited to decoration, underline, etc.